# AngularJS $resource not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to make a GET request using AngularJS and the GET contains email. This is the request:

```
var userResource = $resource('/GetUsers/?username=:username',{username:'@username'});
            userResource.get({'username': 'test1@foot.com'}, function(user) {
                console.log(user);
            });
```

However, the callback function is never called. Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: do you see the network request in fiddler or chrome network tab

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Only thing i can imagine is that the callback function is not allowed to have a parameter. Angularjs Example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
   user.abc = true;
   user.$save();
});
```